# How can I filter matches inside a specific tag?

Tags: javascript, regex, autocorrect

I'm trying to replace all ocurrences of a text in an input field which enhanced with TinyMCE, this has to occur every time the user presses the spacebar (similar to the autocorrect feature in Word).

The problem I have is when the replaced string contains the trigger, it keeps replacing it again and again.
For example replacing "hello" with

```
<span class="replaced">hello world</span>
```

It will replace it again as

```
<span class="replaced"><span class="replaced">hello world</span> world</span>
```

So I have to write a regexp to filter out matches in text that has already been replaced.

Can you help me out?

This is my current code:

```
for (r in autocorrect_replacements) {
  if (newHtml.indexOf(autocorrect_replacements[r][0]) > -1) {
    replacement_html = '<span class="replaced">'+autocorrect_replacements[r][1] + '</span>';
    newHtml = newHtml.replace(autocorrect_replacements[r][0],replacement_html);
    ed.setContent(newHtml);
}
```

I'm not a fan of regular expressions, but I think it's the correct solution in this case.

Comment: Have you considered using something like jQuery's document model parsing, rather than regex?

Comment: Let's suppose I do something like dom = `$(ed.getContent());` to get everything parsed by jQuery every time the user presses the spacebar, and assumig it's not slow as hell, what would I gain, now I have to search in that DOM for all the strings that are not `.replaced` and apply the replacement there, something like: `dom.find(":not[.replaced]")` and then iterate with the replacements...
It might work, but I fear it will not be performant enough for long texts and a lot of replacements.

Comment: RegExp is the wrong solution, and jQuery isn't very much help with manipulating text nodes. You should walk the DOM, and do a replace on each text node. There are plenty of questions on StackOverflow that deal with this. Whatever you do, stop doing the blanket HTML replace that you're currently doing.

Comment: I'm not sure what your keywords are and what the replacements are, but why not only do the replacement on the text right before the cursor?

Comment: Code Jockey: ¿How can I know where the cursor is?

Comment: This page shows all sorts of tricks using cursor position: http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/ -- the actual JavaScript (primarily you would probably use the `getSelectionStart(o)` function) is here:  http://javascript.nwbox.com/cursor_position/cursor.js -- if you think it's possible you could use this stuff, feel free to rephrase and retag your question if you need help

Comment: The primary problem with trying to do this with regex in JavaScript is that lookbehind is not supported

Comment: I got my way... by now. This code seems to work for all the cases I could try:
`match_string = new RegExp("( |\>)"+autocorrect_replacements[r][0]+"(\&|\<)","g");`
`replacement_html = '$1<span class="replaced">'+autocorrect_replacements[r][1] + '</span>$2 ';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex to get the span would be `/<span class="replaced">.*<\/span>/`. Not sure if its the right solution.

You can do something like this:

```
for (r in autocorrect_replacements) {
  if (newHtml.indexOf(autocorrect_replacements[r][0]) > -1) {
        if (!(/<span class="replaced">.*<\/span>/.test(autocorrect_replacements[r][1]))){
            replacement_html = '<span class="replaced">'+autocorrect_replacements[r][1] + '</span>';
            newHtml = newHtml.replace(autocorrect_replacements[r][0],replacement_html);
            ed.setContent(newHtml);
        }
}
```